# Can't run test on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a Java / maven project in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I try to run a test I got the message `Nothing Here`

[image]

Comment: please paste the full code here.

Comment: Have you tried Build > Rebuild project from the top menu in the application?

Comment: do you have any testing framework in your pom?

Comment: Does it work when you run the test via Maven?

Comment: yes, it works from maven

Comment: Could you please try to disable "Gradle" plugin

Comment: You maybe trying to run from .class file instead of .java file@SandroRey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try updating all plugins to latest versions and restarting IDEA.

The issue may be related to [this YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228180). Try disabling the Gradle plugin in **Settings | Plugins** and removing the following lines from `CONFIG\disabled_plugins.txt` file + restart IDEA:

```
org.jetbrains.idea.gradle.ext
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.maven
```

If it doesn't help, attach your `idea.log` file after reproducing the issue (**Help | Show Log in Explorer**).

Comment: Thanks, the disabling gradle plugin worked for me.

Comment: As per the config directory, check out [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) article to see where it's on your system. eg. `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1`

Comment: what if you dont want to disable gradle plugin ?

Comment: @theo, the issue should be already [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228180#focus=Comments-27-4191240.0-0) in versions 2020.2+ of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Disabling the Gradle plugin instantly bricked Android Studio for me. Now I'm being forced to reinstall. :-(

Answer (score -2):

On the latest IDE, this option is more simplified.

right-click on the folder you want to be recognized as a source folder:

Mark *Directory As* -> *Sources Root*

[image]

Comment: Does this resolve the issue they're seeing of being unable to run a test case?  This seems just to mark a folder in blue.

Comment: the code is already inside a source folder as far as i can tell, otherwise that green "play" icon would not be there.